# C++ Prevent the console window from closing when red X is clicked

Tags: windows, visual-c++, console-application

I'm developing a simple C++ console application without classes & objects. 
Is there any method or function to prevent the console from closing when red X button is clicked ? 
I'm using Visual Studio C++ Express 2010 : A simple console application which containes only main.cpp file.
Thank you for answering my question :) !!

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
#include "conio.h"
void main()
{
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    HMENU hmenu = GetSystemMenu(hwnd, FALSE);
    EnableMenuItem(hmenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_GRAYED);
}
```

While we're at it, to re-enable the button:

```
EnableMenuItem(hmenu, SC_CLOSE, MF_ENABLED);
```

... and to set the window's title:

```
char consoleTitle[256];
wsprintf(consoleTitle, _T("My little window"));
SetConsoleTitle((LPCTSTR)consoleTitle);
```

---

I saw that most references used `DeleteMenu` and not `EnableMenuItem`. I preffer the later, as you get more control (enable/disable/greyed-out etc.). For full options, take a look at MSDN [Console Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions) and [Menu Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/menu-functions)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to control the console-window. You need to write up a callback to handle events (such as `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`). You may also use [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get the window-handle, and handle window messages. I have done controlling the window with former method, and not sure about handling specific window message (via window-handle).

Refer [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to trap the close message for a window and prevent it from closing, if you are receiving messages for the window. Unfortunately a console is independent of the program running within it and you don't have that kind of control.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use signals:

```
#include <cstdio>
void my_handler(int param) {
  main();
}
int main() {
  signal(SIGABRT, my_handler);
  signal(SIGTERM, my_handler);
  return 0;
}
```

You should obviously allow an option for the user to close the app, by changing my_handler. my_handler calls main, so whenever the program is closed, my_handler is called, so therefore main is called.