# Win32 Console Disable System Menu Buttons

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to disable/grey a system menu button on the console window, particularly the minimize button. I've tried functions mentioned on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834818/c-prevent-the-console-window-from-closing-when-red-x-is-clicked), but even after using them, the console window still doesn't have the minimize button grayed out. I have also looked into the DeleteMenu() function, but it doesn't seem to have the option to grey out buttons.

Here's the test code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //SetConsoleTitle(L"CPU Information");

    HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
    HMENU hMenu = GetSystemMenu(consoleWindow, FALSE);

    EnableMenuItem(hMenu, SC_MINIMIZE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
    DrawMenuBar(consoleWindow);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GetWindowLong + SetWindowLong FTW!

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HWND consoleWindow  = GetConsoleWindow();
    LONG style = GetWindowLong(consoleWindow , GWL_STYLE);
    style = style & ~(WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
    SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, style);

    return 0;
}
```

This will grey-out and disable both the minimize box in the top-right corner of the window as well as the "minimize" option from the system menu.