# How do I disable or detect mode changes in Windows Console?

Tags: c++, windows, terminal, console, fullscreen

I am experimenting with game development using the Windows Console and I've managed to resize the screen buffer and window to a desired size. The problem is that users can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to force full screen mode - I want to avoid this, because:

1. Entering full screen mode changes the screen buffer size from my carefully planned layout.
2. Returning to windowed mode causes scroll bars to appear.

Ideally I'd like to **disable the full screen mode change** entirely, as a compromise I would want to **detect the mode change** so I can update buffer size variables/remove scroll bars when the change occurs. It was easy enough in Win32 via the `WindowProc`, but Console doesn't seem to have this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21508278/win32-console-disable-system-menu-buttons/21508714#21508714) and modify it to disable other window styles.  Then subclass the HWND's wndproc if necessary to intercept keyboard events such as ALT+ENTER.

Comment: Also, this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference

Comment: @selbie The Console Reference link was handy, specifically the Console WinEvents link on that page. Funny how I hadn't come across that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

While no amount of fiddling with window styles makes any difference (the style changes both going in and coming out of full screen mode), I was able to use the [SetWinEventHook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook) function to detect changes.

```
// Console Layout Change Detection

// Includes:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

// Globals:
HWND g_hWindow;

// EventProc: User defined event procedure callback function
void CALLBACK EventProc(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND wnd, LONG object, LONG child,
                                    DWORD thread, DWORD time) {
    std::cout << "Event received...\n";
    OutputDebugString(L"Event received...\n");

    // ToDo: Respond to layout change here...
}


// Main
int main() {
    // Grab the window handle
    g_hWindow = GetConsoleWindow();

    // Set a window event hook for the console layout changed events such
    // as resize, maximise/restore, enter/exit full screen mode, and others...
    HWINEVENTHOOK eventHook = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT,
                                            NULL, EventProc, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
    if (eventHook != 0) std::cout << "Hook started!\n";
    else std::cout << "Hook not started!\n";

    // Message loop. This one specifically listens for the console layout changed event.
    // If the window handle isn't specified, the hook will pick up ANY console window changes,
    // not just the one associated with this code.
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, g_hWindow, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT, EVENT_CONSOLE_LAYOUT)) {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);

        /*...*/
    }
}
```